# Wicket - Appending values to json schema

Tags: java, json, wicket

**NewForm.java**

```
public class NewForm extends WebPage {

private Bean bean;
private DropDownClass dropdown;


private String selected = "choice";

void init()
{
    bean = new Bean();
    dropdown=new DropDownClass("test");

}

public NewForm(final PageParameters page) {
    init();



    final TextField<String> textname = new TextField<String>("name",Model.of(""));
    textname.setRequired(true);

    final DropDownChoice<String> dropname = new DropDownChoice<String>("type", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "selected"),
            dropdown.getlist());


    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("Form") {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {

            final String name = (String) textname.getModelObject();
            final String dropdown  = (String)dropname.getModelObject();
             bean.add(name,dropdown);
             final String schema = bean.getJsonSchema().toString();
             page.add("schema", schema);

             setResponsePage(new NewForm(page));

        }           

    };

    Label schemalabel = new Label("schema", page.get("schema"));

    add(form);

    form.add(textname);
    form.add(dropname);
    form.add(schemalabel);  
   }
 }
```

**Bean.java**

```
public class Bean 
{

private JSONObject jsonSchema;

public JSONObject getJsonSchema() {
    return jsonSchema;
}

public void setJsonSchema(JSONObject jsonSchema) {
    this.jsonSchema = jsonSchema;
}

public Bean() {     
    jsonSchema = new JSONObject();
}

public void add(String key,String value)
{    
    jsonSchema.put(key, value); // I am able to append values each time using "put" or "append" in JSF but not in WICKET.How can I append values in Wicket?

    //or jsonSchema.append(key, value); //adding values only once and not appending each time,I enter the values in TextField and DropDown 
}
}
```

In CreateForm.java - I have a **Textfield** and **DropDown**. When I enter the values in TextField and DropDown..I am able to convert the values entered in TextField and DropDown as **JSON schema** from method add(String key,String value) in **AttributeInfo.java** and display the schema as - {"name":"abc"} //where **name** is value entered in TextField and **abc** is from DropDown.

I am able to display the schema only once onSubmit But I need to **append the values to schema each time**,I enter in TextField and DropDown onSubmit and display in the samepage.

How can I achieve this in Wicket?

I am just a beginner.Any Help would be appreciated.Thankyou in advance.

Comment: see this tutorial -> [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/)

Comment: Thankyou... Can you please provide an example programmatically?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. Divide problem: wicket DropDown, wicket Model (very important), json data (not connected to wicket). I dont know where is main problem.